# Is there a default icon in ios 7 for settings in a UINavigation Bar?

Tags: ios, ios7, icons

I am looking if an icon like this is standard.(http://bit.ly/SVyCU1)

Is the above image standard?

Comment: First of all, the question title doesn't match the question ("A list of default icons" but the question is "Is the above image standard"). If you're looking for icons, it's a shopping list question. "Is this image standard" is not a programming question.

Comment: Why does this have 113 up votes and is protected then...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813096/are-there-free-iphone-navigation-bar-icon-sets-available

Comment: @chris you should compare your question to question that is 5 years old that isn't a good comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends on what you mean by standard. If you meant that apple uses it in their iOS, then no, but a cog is generally used to represent a "settings" page of some sort.

Comment: Okay by standard I meant including like other bar button icons as the share one and the arrows.

Comment: @chris iOS 7 is more of a "flat" theme, but if you think it goes well with your app and other icons, it's as standard as you need.

Comment: no i'm using a flat theme, just wanted to know if it was already in the ios sdk so i could just call it or if I needed to create a photoshop .png myself

Comment: @chris ah, you should create a png file.